# skipping some if in the for loop python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I've almost finished the game "boom-trach".
the user in put 2 numbers (X,Y), after the the range and the jumps between the numbers(COUNTFROM, JUMP, COUNTUNTIL) and at the last 2 for loops, it should print (in a raw by the way and not column) as described in the code(for instance- x=3 so instead of 6 it will print "boom")
the problem is that id doesn't apply all the if conditions .
it applies only the "Trach" and skipping the others.
at the end it should print a raw of number and "boom", "trach".
THANKS

```
import sys
Z = str(raw_input())
Digits_List = Z.split(" ")
X = int(Digits_List[0])
Y = int(Digits_List[1])
CountFrom = int(Digits_List[2])
jump = int(Digits_List[3])
CountUntil = int(Digits_List[4])

// some basic conditions
if (X<1 or X>9) or (Y<1 or Y>9):
    print "X and Y must be between 1 and 9"

if (jump==0):
    print "Cannot jump from ", CountFrom, " to ", CountUntil

if (CountFrom>0 and CountUntil>0 and jump<0):
    print "Cannot jump from ", CountFrom, " to ", CountUntil

if (CountFrom>0 and CountUntil<0 and jump>0):
    print "Cannot jump from ", CountFrom, " to ", CountUntil

if (CountFrom<0 and CountUntil>0 and jump<0):
    print "Cannot jump from ", CountFrom, " to ", CountUntil

if (CountFrom<0 and CountUntil<0 and jump>0):
    print "Cannot jump from ", CountFrom, " to ", CountUntil

portion = CountFrom - CountUntil

if (portion % jump != 0):
    print "Cannot jump from ", CountFrom, " to ", CountUntil

elements = []
for i in range(CountFrom, CountUntil+jump, jump):
    elements.append(i)

//2 FOR LOOPS- if-s dont work
for num in elements:    
    for num1 in str(num):
        if num1==X and num1==Y:
            print "BOOM-TRACH"
        elif num1==X:
            print "BOOM"
        elif num1== Y:
            print "TRACH"
    elif (num%X==0) and (num%Y==0):
        print "BOOM-TRACH"       
    elif (num%X == 0):
        print "BOOM"        
    elif (num%Y == 0):
        print "TRACH"
    else:
        print num
```

Comment: `str(num) != int(num)` . You might want to consider (`int(num1)`)

Comment: This isn't valid code, and doesn't demonstrate your problem. You get a `SyntaxError` for the C++-style `//` comment (in Python, `//` is division). If you fix those, you get a `SyntaxError` for trying to attach an `elif` to a `for`, which makes no sense. And in that case, it's not at all obvious what you wanted there (and quite possible that whatever's different in your actual code is where the actual problem is that you want us to fix). Please give us real code.

Comment: Also, for the reason karthikr and kindall pointed out, no matter how you structure your `if`s, there is no way this code is printing out "BOOM" as you claim. Describe your actual problem, not the problem you wish you had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if num1==X and num1==Y:
```

Here `num1` is a string. `X` and `Y` are integers. They will never be equal. Convert `num1` to an integer.